# Joomla component form redirect not working

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a form which I dynamically build inside a jquery modal dialog.

```
var $myform = jQuery("<form id='EditForm' method='post' action='index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=edit'></form>");
...
```

It gets processed by the `edit` method in my controller and then I redirect back to the desired page:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent'));
```

This submit from the form works and all is good except the url I get routed back to. It should be

`index.php?option=com_mycomponent` (or the SEF url)

but instead I get:

`components/mycomponent/`

Technically that is the same page but now it screws up any other operation I try to do after that. I'm guessing the fact that I create the form in javascript is part of the problem. I bet if I put

```
<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent') ?>
```

that might work. But I can't do that because this is a form in a separate javascript file where I don't have php available. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you get is correct. It's the SEF URL for `index.php?option=com_mycomponent`.

You can add an Itemid (menu item) so the SEF URLs is prettier. Or you just can skip the JRoute part and you get the non SEF URL.

Update:
To get the currently active menu itemid you just get it from the current URL with either JRequest (depreceated) or JInput (http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput):

```
$itemid = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('Itemid', '0', 'INT');
```

But if there is an active menu item, JRoute should already add it itself.

Comment: Thanks. Removing JRoute does it. But I'd like to keep it. If I hardcode the ItemId to the url that seems to work but do you know how I can generate the ItemID of the current menu. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529567/joomla-how-to-get-the-url-of-a-specific-menu-itemid) didn't work for me.