# Joomla: Get a menu item's URL in regards of the current SEF settinng

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to get a specific menu item's URL from within a module's template file. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529567/joomla-how-to-get-the-url-of-a-specific-menu-itemid) and managed to write the following codes:

```
  function getMenuItemUrl($menuItemId){
    $application = JFactory::getApplication();
    $menu = $application->getMenu();
    $item = $menu->getItem($menuItemId); 
    //to be completed
  }
```

The problem is, in the future, I may change the site's SEF setting, and I want this function to return different URL values depending on current SEF setting. That is, when SEF is on, it should return `mysite.com/index.php/myMenuItemTitle`, otherwise it should return `mysite.com/index.php?option=mycomponent&view=myview&itemId=xxx`, I think there should be some joomla build-in function to do this, but I can't find it.

Comment: How is that different than what normally happens?

Comment: `JRoute::('/index.php?option={$myComponent}&view={$myView}&itemId={$menuItemId}')`. With `Jroute`: will change your non-SEF URL to SEF URL only when you set the option ON. If option set off, then it will return the URL just the way it is.